# Not able to run Android app || 'Gradle-aware make' is missing in app configuaration

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have cloned a private repo that I can't share. that project is built successfully and I can create debug/release apk as well. But I am not able to run it from the run button in android studio.

When I click on the run button, It is not launching in mobile/emulator. Immediately, It says 'launch successfully' Even if it is not starting Gradle run.

So I compared many settings with a sample app that is running as expected, So I found one difference which is in the app configuration(select the app [near run icon] -> Edit configuration).

**That 'Gradle-aware Make' is not there in the 'Before launch' section in the 'General' tab of app configuration.** check the screenshot below:

[image: Missing Gradle-aware Make command]

In the working sample, It is present and we can remove/add it again and again normally. Check the screenshot below:

[image: Sample Gradle-aware Make command]

So How to generate it, Can Someone please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many thanks to [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72193159)

Steps to reproduce Gradle-aware Make in before launch or pre launch:

1. Create a new Android JUnit run config for the ExampleUnitTest test class:

   - Run -> Edit Configurations.
   - Click the "+" button in top-left of the window.
   - Choose "Android JUnit" or "JUnit".
   - Use classpath(-cp) of module "PROJECT_NAME.app.unitTest".
   - Class ".ExampleUnitTest".
2. Run the newly-created run config
3. Quit the IDE
4. Re-launch the IDE, allow Gradle sync to complete
5. Clean the project (Build -> Clean Project)
6. Run the ExampleUnitTest run config again

For me, Above steps are generating the Gradle-aware Make option in before launch section.

Thanks to the actual owner.

Comment: It works like a charm, I tried to solve this issue from 2 days and it works.